# How to read pdf files with pymupdf in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pymupdf

I want to open pdf file through pilihfile pushbutton, then take its name to display on textEdit and display its pdf contents on textEdit_2 by using pymupdf. But i got error said cannot open ('D:/Kuliah/KRIP.pdf', 'PDF Files (*.pdf)'): Invalid argument. I do not know how to fix it.

```
def pilihfile(self):
    files = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Open File", "", "PDF Files (*.pdf)")
    file_name = str(files))

    pdf_document = file_name
    self.textEdit.setText(pdf_document)
    doc = fitz.open(pdf_document)
    hal = doc.pageCount

    for i in range (hal):
        page = doc.loadPage(i)
        page1text = page.get_text().strip()
        self.textEdit_2.setPlainText(page1text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your error message, `pdf_document` has actually the value  of `('D:/Kuliah/KRIP.pdf', 'PDF Files (*.pdf)')`. This is because you use `QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName` with `PyQt5` which returns a `tuple` instead of just a `str` (check [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/757/pyside-qfiledialog-getopenfilename-returns-string-of-tuple-instead-of-just-string)). If that is the case, try:

```
files, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Open File", "", "PDF Files (*.pdf)")
```